# sequential command handler

Tags: c#, .net

I created common handler, which handling commands sequentially:

```
public abstract class SequentialRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
        where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
        where TResponse : class
    {
        private static class TypeLock<T>
        {
            public static readonly object Locker = new object();
        }

        protected abstract Task<TResponse> MonopolyHandle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);

        public Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            lock (TypeLock<TRequest>.Locker)
            {
                return MonopolyHandle(request, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

Using of this common handler:

```
 public class EditCommandHandler : SequentialRequestHandler<EditCommand, ApiResult<Guid>>
    {
        protected override async Task<ApiResult<Guid>> MonopolyHandle(EditCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //handling functionality
        }
    }

public class SaveCommandHandler : SequentialRequestHandler<SaveCommand, ApiResult<Guid>>
    {
        protected override async Task<ApiResult<Guid>> MonopolyHandle(SaveCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //handling functionality
        }
    }
```

How change `SequentialRequestHandler`, that he processes the commands sequentially without `lock` ?

Comment: The question isn't clear. I can't tell which things aren't happening sequentially that you want to make happen sequentially.

Comment: So that the handler method MonopolyHandle is called one thread mode, sequentially as in the example.

Comment: If what you want is to ensure that across all instances of the handler, all commands regardless of type are processed sequentially then you'll need some sort of lock. A question to consider is why they must execute sequentially. I'd try to eliminate the need. Solving the problem is good. Making it disappear is better.